# How to solve a simple quadratic equation with Sympy?

Tags: sympy

```
solve(-14.4*(x**2)+71.8*x+5.083, x)
```

result is None. how come? My calculation by hand gives two roots, 5.0559 and -0.063

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you are not using the most current version. I get

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x')
x
>>> solve(-14.4*(x**2)+71.8*x+5.083, x)
[-0.0698162934055920, 5.05592740451670]
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally:

```
import sympy as sp

y = 'a * x ** 2 + b * x + c' # for example a quadratic polynomial

s = sp.var('x a b c')        # define four symbols as variables

print(sp.solve(y,  s ))      # sympy solves y(a,b,c,x) for each of a, b, c, x
print(sp.solve(y,  x ))      # sympy solves Y(a,b,c,x) for x treating a, b, c as constants
print(sp.solve(y, 'x'))      # sympy solves Y(a,b,c,x) for x treating a, b, c as constants
```

Yields:

```
[(x, -(b*x + c)/x**2, b, c)]
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
```

While:

```
s = sp.var('x')              # define one symbol as a varible

print(sp.solve(y,  s ))      # sympy solves Y(a,b,c,x) for x treating a, b, c as constants
print(sp.solve(y,  x ))      # sympy solves Y(a,b,c,x) for x treating a, b, c as constants
print(sp.solve(y, 'x'))      # sympy solves Y(a,b,c,x) for x treating a, b, c as constants
```

Returns:

```
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
```